# Prepopulate new Taxonomy Term's Parent via the URL

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, uri

I currently have a views page made up of taxonomy terms. Each term has a link next to it that redirects to the Add Term page. The add term page should auto-populate the parent of the corresponding term.

The [Prepopulate](https://www.drupal.org/project/prepopulate) module should make something like this possible and it works with all other fields, but not with the Parent select field for some reason.

I am using the following query parameter=`?edit[parent][]=24` in the URL (where 24 is the value).

Any help getting this to work with [Prepopulate](https://www.drupal.org/project/prepopulate), or using another method would be extremely helpful. Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the fieldset name must also be included, and for whatever reason the "[]" is also not required. To get it to work, I used the following:

```
?edit[relations][parent]=24
```